# Check if the current user has permission to edit current node

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I'm using [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module to add permissions on specific nodes.
 in my `.theme` file I want to Check if the current user has permission to edit the current node.

Comment: Shouldn’t this be handled by the route callback / link function?

Comment: @Kevin, Thanks for your help. Can you provide me with some details or link help me using callback / link function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found it and working great.

```
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(NID);
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $check = $node->access('update', $user);
```